# Pass Script Parameters

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm having some trouble passing in Script Parameters for this code. The code doesn't seem to be reading in any values for the parameters from this execution log and error message: https://photos.app.goo.gl/FXKYkFAXMctP4WhY6

/** 
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(["N/record", "N/log", "N/runtime"], function (record, log, runtime) {

```
function afterSubmit(context) {

    // Gather your variables
    var newRec = context.newRecord;
    var freightCost = newRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_freight_cost'
    });
    var freightItem = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter('custscript_freight_item');
    var handlingItem = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter('custscript_handling_item');
    var salesOrderId = newRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'createdfrom'
    });
    log.debug('Sales Order ID', salesOrderId);
    log.error({
        title: 'Freight Cost',
        details: freightCost
    });
    log.error({
        title: 'Freight Item',
        details: freightItem
    });

    // Transform the Sales Order into an Invoice
    var invoiceRecord = record.transform({
        fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
        fromId: salesOrderId,
        toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
        isDynamic: true
    });
    log.error({
        title: 'Debug Entry',
        details: invoiceRecord
    });
    invoiceRecord.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    invoiceRecord.setCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        text: freightItem
    });
    invoiceRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'amount',
        value: freightCost
    });
    invoiceRecord.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    invoiceRecord.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    invoiceRecord.setCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        text: handlingItem
    });
    invoiceRecord.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });

    // Here is how you set a body field
    invoiceRecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_freight_cost',
        value: freightCost,
        ignoreFieldChange: true
    });

    // Submit the record
    var rid = invoiceRecord.save();
    log.debug('Saved Record', rid);
}
return {
    afterSubmit: afterSubmit 
    };
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try passing an object into the `getParameter` function like this?

```
var freightItem = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({ name: 'custscript_freight_item' });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `setCurrentSublistText` for setting the item instead of `setCurrentSublistValue`? Seems like `1038` is an item internalid and not an item name. If it is an internal id you should switch `setCurrentSublistText` with `setCurrentSublistValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your error code is "INVALID_RCRD_TRANSFORM", the problem is likely that your Sales Order cannot be transformed to an Invoice. This could be because your 'createdfrom' field on your record is not a Sales Order or the order is not in the correct status to be Invoiced.

Make sure that your createdFrom is indeed a Sales Order. Otherwise, your Sales Order might simply not be in the correct status to be invoiced. Have a look at Eric's answer on this question: [Transform sales order to invoice error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784013/transform-sales-order-to-invoice-error)